# Property Decorator not replacing definition?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have code similar to the following situation where I'm trying to replace a property based on a decorator

```
export function DecorateMe() {
    return function(component: any, propertyKey: string) {
        Object.defineProperty(component, propertyKey, {
            get: () => {
                ...
            },
            set: (value: boolean) => {
                ...
            }
        });
    };
}
class Parent {}

@Component()
class Child extends Parent {
    @DecorateMe()
    public property: string;
}
```

However at runtime I'm seeing `property` defined as normal, hiding the `get/set` methods added to the prototype.

According to the TypeScript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) and [this tutorial](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-ii), I was expecting this to work.

I am using Angular, so I am unsure if that could be having an impact.

Comment: As per tutorial you cited, you need to delete the property by calling `if (delete this[key]) {` - which you does not seem to be doing

Comment: @WandMaker I tried that as well, however the `this` in the tutorial is not the class or its prototype. I also tried with `component`, but neither worked

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your function is for not property decorators.  Use below code:

```
export function DecorateMe(component: any, propertyKey: string) {
   var _val = component[propertyKey];

  if (delete component[propertyKey]) {
    Object.defineProperty(component, propertyKey, {
        get: () => {
            console.log("Getter called ", _val);
            return _val;
        },
        set: (value: any) => {
            _val = value;
            console.log("Setter called ", _val);
        }
    });
  }
}
```